# Пишу пинпонг с SFML , как правльно написать коллизию для спрайта SwagBall относительно спрайтов player

Tags: c++, sfml

(код в методе класса `SwagBall` описывающий коллизию)

```
void SwagBall::updateWindowBoundsCollision()
{`
if(swagBallBounds.left + swagBallBounds.width >= player.sprite2.getGlobalBounds().left)
    {
        movementSpeed = -4.f;
    }`
}
```

Такой вариант работает не правильно, шар отталкивается даже от месть где нет спрайта игрока, спрайты игроков расположены по краям.

Answer (score 0):

Функции должна быть такой

```
if(this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().top + this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().height >= target->getSize().y)
{
    this->sprite.setPosition(this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().left, target->getSize().y - this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().height);
}
```

и вызывать в Game::update();